# Scrapy CrawlSpider - Yielding multiple items from a single spider

Tags: scrapy

i'm very new either with Scrapy or Python so my vocabulary might be inacurate

I'm trying to get two different items with my CrawlSpider, but i cannot find out how to do it. Currently only the first item "CourseItem" is crawled, the other one is not executed at all.

I believe it's probably the way im calling everything but can't figure exactly what. (callback=parse_course) ?

Each function is working properly if i make one spider per item.
I've tried to put everything in the same function but it doesn't help either.

spider.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
import datetime
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy_spider.items import CourseItem, PronosticItem
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class GenycourseSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = 'genycourse'
    allowed_domains = ['www.geny.com']
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow='/partants-pmu/*'), callback="parse_course"
            ),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        date = datetime.date(2016, 03, 12)
        datefin = datetime.date(2016, 03, 12)
        while date <= datefin:
            url = 'http://www.geny.com/reunions-courses-pmu?date=%s' % date.isoformat()
            date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            yield Request(url)

    def parse_course(self, response):

#Recupération des valeurs
        date = response.request.url
        reunion = response.xpath("//*[@id='yui-main']/div/div[2]/div[1]/text()").extract_first().strip()
        course = response.xpath("//*[@id='yui-main']/div/div[2]/div[3]/span/strong/text()[1]").extract_first().strip()
        type = response.xpath("//*[@id='yui-main']/div/div[2]/span").extract_first().strip()
        hippodrome = response.xpath("//*[@id='navigation']/a[3]/text()").extract_first()
#Nettoyage du resultat
#On isole la date
        date = date[33:43]
#On coupe au niveau de ( et on garde le numéro de la réunion
        temp = re.split(r"\(", reunion)
        reunion = temp [1]
        reunion = re.sub(r'[R\)]', '', reunion)
#On identifie les courses et les stocke
        type = re.findall(r'(Attel|Plat|Haies|Steeple-chase|Cross|Mont)', type)
        plat = "Plat" in type
        obstacle = "Haies" or "Steeple-chase" in type
#On met en place l'objet
        courseinfo = CourseItem()
        courseinfo['date'] = date
        courseinfo['reunion'] = reunion
        courseinfo['course'] = course
        courseinfo['type'] = type
        courseinfo['hippodrome'] = hippodrome
        loopcheval = 1
        numerocheval = 1
        while numerocheval != None:
            numerocheval = response.xpath("//*[@id='tableau_partants']/tbody/tr["+ str(loopcheval) +"]/td[1]/text()").extract_first()
            if plat is True:
                cotecheval = response.xpath("//*[@id='tableau_partants']/tbody/tr["+ str(loopcheval) +"]/td[12]/text()").extract_first().strip()
            elif obstacle is True:
                cotecheval = response.xpath("//*[@id='tableau_partants']/tbody/tr["+ str(loopcheval) +"]/td[11]/text()").extract_first().strip()
            else:
                cotecheval = response.xpath("//*[@id='tableau_partants']/tbody/tr["+ str(loopcheval) +"]/td[10]/text()").extract_first().strip()
            if numerocheval is not None:
                courseinfo['numero'] = numerocheval
                courseinfo['cote'] = cotecheval
                yield courseinfo
                loopcheval = loopcheval + 1        

    def parse_prono(self, response):

        date = response.request.url
        reunion = response.xpath("//*[@id='yui-main']/div/div[2]/div[1]/text()").extract_first().strip()
        course = response.xpath("//*[@id='yui-main']/div/div[2]/div[3]/span/strong/text()[1]").extract_first().strip()


        date = date[33:43]

        temp = re.split(r"\(", reunion)
        reunion = temp [1]
        reunion = re.sub(r'[R\)]', '', reunion)

        pronoinfo = PronosticItem()
        pronoinfo['date'] = date
        pronoinfo['reunion'] = reunion
        pronoinfo['course'] = course

        ligne = 1
        testpronostique = pronostiqueur = response.xpath("//*[@id='selectionsPresse']/table/tr[1]/td[1]/div/div[1]").extract_first()

        if testpronostique is None:
            pronoinfo['pronostiqueur'] = 'Pas de pronostic'
            pronoinfo['premier'] = 0
            pronoinfo['second'] = 0
            yield pronoinfo
        else:
            while ligne <= 3:
                while ligne <= 2:
                    colonne = 1
                    while colonne <= 3:
                        pronostiqueur = response.xpath("//*[@id='selectionsPresse']/table/tr["+ str(ligne) +"]/td["+ str(colonne) +"]/div/div[1]").extract_first()
                        pronostiqueur = re.findall(r'(Radio|AIP|Sud|Presse|Casaque|Courrier|che)', pronostiqueur)
                        pronostique = response.xpath("//*[@id='selectionsPresse']/table/tr["+ str(ligne) +"]/td["+ str(colonne) +"]/div/div[2]/text()").extract_first().strip()
                        pronostique = re.split(r" - ", pronostique)
                        premier = pronostique [0]
                        second = pronostique [1]
                        pronoinfo['pronostiqueur'] = pronostiqueur
                        pronoinfo['premier'] = premier
                        pronoinfo['second'] = second
                        yield pronoinfo
                        colonne = colonne + 1
                        if colonne == 4:
                            ligne = ligne + 1
                if ligne == 3:
                        pronostiqueur = response.xpath("//*[@id='selectionsPresse']/table/tr[3]/td[1]/div/div[1]").extract_first()
                        pronostiqueur = re.findall(r'(Radio|AIP|Sud|Presse|Casaque|Courrier|che)', pronostiqueur)
                        pronostique = response.xpath("//*[@id='selectionsPresse']/table/tr[3]/td[1]/div/div[2]/text()").extract_first().strip()
                        pronostique = re.split(r" - ", pronostique)
                        premier = pronostique [0]
                        second = pronostique [1]
                        pronoinfo['pronostiqueur'] = pronostiqueur
                        pronoinfo['premier'] = premier
                        pronoinfo['second'] = second
                        yield pronoinfo
                        ligne = ligne + 1
```

items.py

```py
class CourseItem(scrapy.Item):
    date = scrapy.Field()
    reunion = scrapy.Field()
    course = scrapy.Field()
    type = scrapy.Field()
    hippodrome = scrapy.Field()
    numero = scrapy.Field()
    cote = scrapy.Field()

class PronosticItem(scrapy.Item):
    date = scrapy.Field()
    reunion = scrapy.Field()
    course = scrapy.Field()
    pronostiqueur = scrapy.Field()
    premier = scrapy.Field()
    second = scrapy.Field()
```

Im expecting to get both CourseItem() and PronosticItem() to get populated and sent to pipeplines and not just only CourseItem()

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You don't `yield` anything to `self.parse_prono` callback that's why you don't `yield` `PronosticItem()` item.

Comment: where are you calling  `parse_prono` function?  yielding of `PronosticItem()` is inside that function.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but that's my question, how in my situation i can call parse_prono function ? By doing a def parse and calling the two from there ?